# How can I clone a table row using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clone my tr class row. So when the user is clicking at a button, the row will clone and will set below the last row.

I currently use the following code, only it will not work properly. I probably not be correct.

JS:

```
var row = jQuery('.ui-sortable').closest('.ui-sortable').find('tbody tr.row.ui-sortable:last-child');
var clone = row.clone();
```

The cloned field looks like this:

HTML markup:

```
echo '<tbody class="ui-sortable">';
echo '<tr class="row">';
echo '<td class="order">1</td>';

// Do some stuff inside the row.

echo '<td class="remove"><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></td>';
echo '</tr>'; // End .row
echo '</tbody>';
```

I think that the first snippet of code at the javascript is not correctly.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but you're right that the first snippet of code won't work.  You don't need the `.closest()` part at all, nor the `.find()` really. I can't give you the right answer because I don't know how you want to identify the row.

Comment: First my excuues. What I exactly want is when the user clicks on the button add new, that row (see html markup) is cloned and below the last row row class is placed. Concept behind this story is that for a field of a WordPress Metabox want to duplicate through javascript. Hope this is for you all clear now! If not I will give it a new try ;) Thank you for your respond!

Comment: Ah, I see; the button is in the same row. OK that makes sense.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry note that the button in the row to delete the row is. The button for a new state out of the row ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is *inside* the row you want to clone, then something like the following should work.  (It may not be exactly right, but it's probably close).

```
$('#your-table').on('click', '.copy-row-button', function() {
  var 
    $table = $(this).closest('table'),
    $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
    $newRow = $row.clone();

  $table.append($('<tbody/').append($newRow));
});
```

I appended the row wrapped in a new `<tbody>` element because Internet Explorer may have problems appending a `<tr>` to an existing table body.

The code also uses made-up selectors for the table and the button; you can make your page with whatever id/class values you need.

Comment: I have tried your code, but it won't be working... I tried to play around and looks for other codes and came up with next snippet of code. http://snippi.com/s/lhro6ge
It will work, when I click on the button class "repeatable-add" the field will duplicate and the value will reset for the next field. When I would like to update my post (use this for my plugin inside WordPress) the field is gone... >>

Comment: When I add a new field and set some new value in it, it will override the first row input. So when I set in the first row "Hello", clone the field, and put in the second row a value of "Thank you", save/update the post there will be only one field with the latest value, "Thank you". I think it will override the other field. Hope somebody can help me fix this! Thank you in advance!